# JSF EL with two bean attributes

Tags: jsf, el

Why does this code not work if I compare the two values in the rendered attribute

```
<c:forEach var="eintrag" items="#{alleEintraege.eintrage}">
    <p:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-info" value="bearbeiten"
                     rendered="#{eintrag.email eq '#{mamanagedBean.benutzer.mit.email}'}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Both attributes are right.
If I put them in a `h:outputText` tag they show the right text.
Just in the combination they won't work.

Comment: Probably a duplicate. Use `#{eintrag.email eq mamanagedBean.benutzer.mit.email}`.

Comment: `#{`indicates start of an EL expression, not the start of a variable.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517928/access-map-value-in-el-using-a-variable-as-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare it that way:

```
<c:forEach var="eintrag" items="#{alleEintraege.eintrage}">
    <p:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-info" value="bearbeiten" rendered="#{eintrag.email eq mamanagedBean.benutzer.mit.email}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost there, just fix the nested expression as it would evaluate as a `String` instead of what you're expecting.

You should compare both bean properties inside the same expression in order to have the desired effect.

**Example**

```
<p:commandButton rendered="#{managedBean1.email eq managedBean2.email}" />
```